# GTK+ Glade and CSS

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk3, gtk#

I've made a simple glade UI file for my programm. It contains of 2 textfields and 1 button. And also I made a css style which contains 1 button class named "button". When I added this file in Glade as "Custom CSS provider" it changed my button style within the editor.

After that I created the UI using GtkBuilder (I am using GTK# 3.20 bindings + C#).

```
Builder b = new Builder ();
b.AddFromFile ("login.xml");
b.Autoconnect (this);
```

It created my simple form (2 fields and 1 button) but there is no CSS Style applied to it. So I checked XML code of my UI file and found out that there is no reference to CSS exept of this:

```
<style>
      <class name="button"/>
</style>
```

After that I read that I need CssProvider. So I created one.

```
CssProvider css = new CssProvider ();
css.LoadFromPath ("ui_common.css");
```

But nothing happened. So, how should I apply custom CSS to my Builder UI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there; the last step is to take the GtkCssProvider and add it to a GtkStyleContext.

Since you are using a `.ui` file and a `.css` file, I assume you want to make your CSS apply to all widgets in the application. In that case, you can use `gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen()`, passing `gdk_screen_get_default()` as the GdkScreen. (This should be safe; it's what the GTK+ Inspector does. IIRC there was a more specific reason why this should be safe...)

You can also do this to individual widgets using `gtk_widget_get_style_context()` and `gtk_style_context_add_provider()`.

In both cases, use `GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION` as the priority for application-local CSS.

(I do not know the C# names; sorry.)

Comment: Oh my god, thanks! It works! Really appreciate your answer!